# How to achieve a plain and clean UV edge export ?

Tags: uv

When I export my UV layout, I get the UV layout with faces shaded so to say (fig 2). Is there a way to get a pure edges export without faces being shaded (fig 1)  ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you export the UV layout you have options on the left of the file browser. You need to set the *Fill Opacity* to '0':

[image]

Comment: Sorry, are you saying this worked for you or not?